# How to install Pulseaudio on ubuntu 13.10

Tags: installation, command-line, sound, 13.10, pulseaudio

I uninstalled pulseaudio because I was going to use alsa but I am having problems with that too. So I just want to get pulseaudio back.

Comment: I presume you uninstalled pulseaudio using `sudo apt-get remove pulseaudio` or something, so can't you use the inverse `sudo apt-get install pulseaudio`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is pulseaudio available in ubuntu software center? You can easily install from there in one click. Or you can go through the following link 
 http://www.webupd8.org/2013/03/install-pulseaudio-with-built-in-system.html